# how to properly escape a lucene query?

Tags: java, lucene, escaping

I'm quite new to Lucene and recently, I ran into a problem. I have a lucene document that looks like this:

```
--- type ---
gene
--- id ---
xla:379474
--- alt_id ---
emb:BC054227
gb:BC054227
ncbi-geneid:379474
ncbi-gi:148230166
rs:NM_001086315
rs:NP_001079784
unigene:Xl.24622
xla:379474
```

I created the query bellow in order to retrieve that document. It works fine for `altId = 379474` but not for `altId = ncbi-geneid:379474` or `Xl.24622`. I guessed altId must be escaped and tried `String altId = QueryParser.escape(altId)` with no luck. Is that the expected behavior of the query?, I'm I missing something?

```
Query query1 = new TermQuery(new Term("type", "gene"));
Query query2 = new TermQuery(new Term("alt_Id", altId));

BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
query.add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

By the way I'm running lucene v3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not related to escaping but to the way `alt_id` was indexed and the use of `TermQuery`. There is 2 possible solutions:

1. Replace `TermQuery` with the output from `QueryParser.parse`, with `QueryParser` created with `StandardAnalyzer`.
2. Or index `alt_id` as `Index.NOT_ANALYZED` and stick with `TermQuery`.

I implemented the last one and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.
Try and let me know.
http://www.strongd.net/?p=44

Comment: As I said, I tried escaping the query using the query parser (`QueryParser.escape(altId)`) with no luck. I also tried the pattern alternative proposed in [link](http://www.strongd.net/?p=44) and i can see that the user input is escaped `alt_id:xla\:379474` but still get no results when running the query.

Comment: Please copy the interesting text into the answer as the link can die any moment. As it has.